# how to divide sub-categories in rows of 3 columns in dropdown menu

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have long dropdown list its displaying in one column....but i want it to display in 3 columns , can anybody help me to do that....[image]

reference:

http://gotofunction.com/question/3309/how-to-divide-categories-in-rows-of-three-columns

Answer (score 0):

you are using rwd theme so got to `skin/frontend/rwd/defaut/css/styles.css` and change replace this in that..

**styles.css 3433**

```
.nav-primary li.level1 a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
```

**styles.css 3529**

```
.nav-primary li.level1 a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: what does styles.css 3433 and 3529 mean????

Comment: these are styles.css line to change

Comment: its displaying in 3 column but not displaying properly......its not displaying the list of subcategory.....by on hover only i can see the sub category..

Comment: you are talking about second level or third level

Comment: second level, now I got the solution for that problem,but still its not displaying properly,,,,,,,,,,

Answer (score -1):

you need to enable mega menu, check if your theme is having mega menu option if not you have to use custom css